# 1px gaps appearing on transformed element in Firefox - Subpixel rounding issue

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

Adding transform attributes to a div seems to make Firefox round width values to the nearest number making gaps appear between columns.

I've made an jsFiddle example. Resize the the window in various browsers and gaps will appear and disappear in-between the div's. This does not happen in Chrome safari or IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/afz79xmr/

Is this a bug or am I missing some *special* css properties?

---

Required code

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}
.item{
    transform:skewY(2deg);
    transition: transform .6s ease,  background .6s ease;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    background: red;
}

.item:hover{
    transform:skewY(5deg);
    background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
<br />
<h1>resize my window</h1>
```

Comment: ^^^ note: You may need to view the above snippet as 'full page'.

Comment: Nothing? Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing I've managed to solve my issue by adding this line of CSS:

```
border-right: 1px solid transparent;
```

[See here for the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afz79xmr/1/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item {
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  transition: transform .6s ease, background .6s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}
.a {} .b {
  left: 20%;
}
.c {
  left: 40%;
}
.d {
  left: 60%;
}
.e {
  left: 80%;
}
.item:hover {
  transform: skewY(4deg);
  background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a item">a</div>
  <div class="b item">b</div>
  <div class="c item">c</div>
  <div class="d item">d</div>
  <div class="e item">e</div>
</div>
<br />
<h1>resize my window</h1>
```

**UPDATE**

I've since noticed this workaround creates a few issues:

1. Messes up other browsers
2. Border-right makes .item overflow out of its container

My solution is to move everything into a firefox "at-rule"

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .item{
        border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .item:last-of-type{
        border-right: 0;
    }    
}
```

[See here for the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afz79xmr/8/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item {
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  transition: transform .6s ease, background .6s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .item {
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  .item:last-of-type {
    border-right: 0;
  }
}

.b {
  left: 20%;
}
.c {
  left: 40%;
}
.d {
  left: 60%;
}
.e {
  left: 80%;
}
.item:hover {
  transform: skewY(4deg);
  background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a item">a</div>
  <div class="b item">b</div>
  <div class="c item">c</div>
  <div class="d item">d</div>
  <div class="e item">e</div>
</div>
<br />
<h1>resize my window</h1>
```

Comment: This is some interesting behaviour, nice workaround :) still a little jumpy.